# Error saving Asp.Net core Ef Entity after using Automapper

Tags: asp.net-core, automapper, entity-framework-core

I have an asp.net core 1 app with ef core 1.0 and automapper 5.1.1.
  I receive from the web page a viewmodel of an entity and I'm trying to map directly to the ed entity.

In the startup for the map I declare this rule

```
   cfg.CreateMap<AnagraficaVm, Anagrafiche>()
     .ForMember( dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.Ignore() );
```

The Id in both the en entity and viewmodel are identical.
In the mvc controller I try to map the viewmodel this way:

```
var anagrafica = await _db.Anagrafiche.FirstOrDefaultAsync(r => r.Id == id);
if (anagrafica == null) return null;
    _mapper.Map(model, anagrafica);
```

when I call the `SaveChangesAsync` I receive the error message

> The instance of entity type 'Anagrafiche' cannot be tracked because
>   another instance of this type with the same key is already being
>   tracked. When adding new entities, for most key types a unique
>   temporary key value will be created if no key is set (i.e. if the key
>   property is assigned the default value for its type). If you are
>   explicitly setting key values for new entities, ensure they do not
>   collide with existing entities or temporary values generated for other
>   new entities. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one
>   entity instance with a given key value is attached to the context.

How can I avoid this error message and map the data from view model to an existing object?

Comment: when you call the `SaveChangesAsync()` ? Can you complete your code above ?

Comment: I have the same problem , could you solved this?